# Rails 3 template not loading in jQuery UI Tabs

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, routes

I have a Profile in my Rails 3 app. When the Profile is viewed, the Profile's about information shows in a `div` container by default. What I want to do is replace the "about" information in the `div` with messages from the User when a "messages" link is clicked. (The messages should load according to the `profile_messages` template.) To do this, I turned to jQuery UI Tabs.

So the "about" information exists in Tab-1. The "Messages" is in a template called `profile_messages` that I've tried loading from both the ProfilesController and the MessagesController.

I've gotten a lot of help here on SO to get to where I'm at. However, for some reason I can't get the actual messages to show up. What happens when I click "messages is I see the error message in my jQuery. If I inspect the element, I see this:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) `profile_messages`
```

Here is my code. If anyone can help me figure out what's going on I'd appreciate it greatly.

**`ProfilesShow show.html.erb:`**

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul id="infoContainer">
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">About</a></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Messages", "/profiles/profile_messages", :remote => true %></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
  </div><!-- end profile-about -->
```

**`profile_messages.html.erb`:**

```
<div id="tabs-2">
<% for 'message' in @user.messages %>
  <div class="message-1">
  </div>
</div><!-- end messages -->
<% end %>
```

**`ProfilesController`:**

```
def show
  @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
  @user = User.find(@profile.user_id)
end
```

**`Routes.rb`**:

```
resources :messages do
  resources :responses
end
resource :messages do
  collection do
    get :profile_messages
  end
end
```

**`profile_messages.js.erb`:**

```
$( "#tabs" ).html( "<%= escape_javascript( render(@profile.messages) ) %>" );
```

**From `rake routes`:**

```
message GET  /messages/:id(.:format) {:action=>"show", :controller=>"messages"}
profile GET  /profiles/:id(.:format) {:action=>"show", :controller=>"profiles"}
profile_messages_messages GET  /messages/profile_messages(.:format {:action=>"profile_messages", :controller=>"messages"}
```

**jQuery UI Tabs:**

```
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
        spinner: '<img src="">' },{
        ajaxOptions: {
            error: function( xhr, status, index, anchor ) {
                $( anchor.hash ).html(
                    "There was an error loading this tab. Please try again." );
            }
        }
    });
});
```

As I said, I'm really close so if anyone can help me figure out what I'm doing wrong I'd appreciate it.

**UPDATE:** If I switch the route from `profiles/profile_messages` to `messages/profile_messages` here is the HTML output of the jQuery UI Tabs:

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul id="infoContainer">
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="messages/profile_messages" data-remote="true">Messages</a></li>
  </ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
```

Here is what I see in Firebug:

```
<div id="tabs" class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
  <ul id="infoContainer" class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active"><a href="#tabs-1">About</a></li>
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><a href="#ui-tabs-1" data-remote="true">Messages</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom">
  </div>
</div>
```

The fact that Firebug shows the second link as #ui-tabs-1 seems odd to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the combined efforts of folks here on SO I was able to get this to work. Check out these questions for more code:

[Exclude application layout in Rails 3 div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697317/exclude-application-layout-in-rails-3-div)

[Rails 3 jQuery UI Tabs issue loading with Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693012/rails-3-jquery-ui-tabs-issue-loading-with-ajax/7698207#comment9363399_7698207)

Answer (score 0):

The routes output says it all: profile_messages_messages, but you also need to append _path--if you were using the generated path variable and not using a string path.

Comment: Aaarg phone won't let me delete; it's only a partial answer.

Comment: Gotcha, I'll check back later. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @ Dave Newton, can you complete your answer when you can?

Comment: @tvalent2 Can you put the project up on github/etc?

Answer (score 0):

Does this route exist?

```
/profiles/profile_messages
```

This is what you are calling from your link_to.  From your routes output, it seems this should be:

```
/messages/profile_messages
```

Comment: So I switched to that but still get failed resource. I've just added an update at the bottom of my question if you have any ideas.